# Primefaces lightbox next button dosnt works

Tags: primefaces, lightbox

Hello I have a problem with lightbox primefaces component.

I use this code to test it:

```
<p:lightBox id="lightbox" styleClass="imagebox" style="text-align: center"> 

                <h:outputLink value="http://localhost:8080/cmw/media/11672-2462271033083613369.jpg" title="Sopranos 1">  
            <h:graphicImage value="http://localhost:8080/cmw/media/11672-2462271033083613369.jpg"/>  
        </h:outputLink>  

        <h:outputLink value="http://localhost:8080/cmw/media/11672-2462271033083613369.jpg" title="Sopranos 2">  
            <h:graphicImage value="http://localhost:8080/cmw/media/11672-2462271033083613369.jpg" />  
        </h:outputLink>  



        </p:lightBox>
```

When I press next button to view second image it keeps loading and never shows up the image.

What could be the problem? Logs don't shows any error

I compared the estructure with primefaces demo and its seems to be the same:

Primefaces demo:

```
<div id="lighbox1" class="imagebox"><a href="../images/sopranos/sopranos1.jpg" title="Sopranos 1"><img id="sopranos1_small" src="/showcase/images/sopranos/sopranos1_small.jpg"></a><a href="../images/sopranos/sopranos2.jpg" title="Sopranos 2"><img id="sopranos2_small" src="/showcase/images/sopranos/sopranos2_small.jpg"></a><a href="../images/sopranos/sopranos3.jpg" title="Sopranos 3"><img id="sopranos3_small" src="/showcase/images/sopranos/sopranos3_small.jpg"></a><a href="../images/sopranos/sopranos4.jpg" title="Sopranos 4"><img id="sopranos4_small" src="/showcase/images/sopranos/sopranos4_small.jpg"></a></div>
```

My page:

```
<div id="lightbox" style="text-align: center" class="imagebox"><a href="http://localhost:8080/cmw/media/11672-2462271033083613369.jpg" title="Sopranos 1"><img src="http://localhost:8080/cmw/media/11672-2462271033083613369.jpg" alt=""></a><a href="http://localhost:8080/cmw/media/11672-2462271033083613369.jpg" title="Sopranos 2"><img src="http://localhost:8080/cmw/media/11672-2462271033083613369.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
```